# How to make object/properties show in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my directive to show an input field:

**JS:**

```
 .directive('isField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{prop}}</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
        '<label ng-if="obj.prop" class="control-label" style="font-weight:normal;">Yes</label>' +
        '<label ng-if="!obj.prop" class="control-label" style="font-weight:normal;">No</label>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>',
        scope: {
          obj: "@obj",
          prop: "@prop",
        },
        controller: function(){
        },
        link: function(scope,elem,attr,ctrl){
        }
    };
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<is-field obj="pano" prop="isOutRoom" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ng-binding">isOutRoom</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <!-- ngIf: obj.prop -->
      <!-- ngIf: !obj.prop -->
      <label ng-if="!obj.prop" class="control-label ng-scope" style="font-weight:normal;">No</label>
      <!-- end ngIf: !obj.prop -->
    </div>
  </div>
</is-field>
```

But `obj.prop` is not being evaluated, the directive shows `No` even when `obj.prop` is `true`.

Sample JSON:

```
pano:
{
  "objectId": "566f915b00b0814d65fa12e0",
  "isVirtualRoom": true,
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `scope:` part of the directive?

Comment: Try this         
**scope: {
          obj: "=obj",
          prop: "=prop",
        }**

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in your template and precisely in ng-if, you template should be like

```
 .directive('isField', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div class="form-group">' +
  '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{prop}}</label>' +
  '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
    '<label ng-if="prop" class="control-label" style="font-weight:normal;">Yes</label>' +
    '<label ng-if="!prop" class="control-label" style="font-weight:normal;">No</label>' +
  '</div>' +
'</div>',
    scope: {
      obj: "@obj",
      prop: "@prop",
    },
    controller: function($scope){

    },
    link: function(scope,elem,attr,ctrl){
    }
};
```

})

this is a [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3q4xD8YTeW065PuKc27?p=preview)